# imagejpeg() permission denied despite 777 permissions

Tags: php, imagejpeg

My script keeps outputting this and I have no idea why.

```html
Intercepted error

imagejpeg(/home/admin/domains/eso-database.com/public_html/signatur/1987300/signatur.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Code:  2
Line:  407
File:  /home/admin/domains/eso-database.com/public_html/api/cronjobs/create_signatures.php
Dir:  /home/admin/domains/eso-database.com/public_html/api/cronjobs
```

however the signatur folder and all its subfolders and files are set to 777 permissions (Yes I know its unsafe and no this environment is not used for anything significant) and the owner is set to apache (www-data equivalent on Centos). php is also not running in safemode. Still my script won't write the image.

I have no idea what else I can do.

--edit--
whoami reported 'admin', tried setting that as the owner, also did not work.

Comment: Try to <?php echo exec('whoami'); ?> who you are

Comment: Hmm whoami returns 'admin', that's weird

Comment: Although, with it set to admin it also does not work

Comment: The first you try to change CHMOD and CHOWN your file you run code to 777 and www-data. The second try to change CHMOD and CHOWN of directory to 777 and www-data. I'm sure will be okay. Please try